# How to iterate through images for extracting features with VGG16?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, keras

I am following [this code](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16) from Keras:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

features = model.predict(x)
```

That is an example for a single image. How can I make it for a bunch of images? Let say I have 2000 images and I am expecting to have features shape as (2000, 7, 7, 512)

Comment: Your model already handles batches of input, you can just call `model.predict` with an array of images as a batch, for example with  `(2000, 224, 224, 3)` shape and it will give you an output of `(2000, 7, 7, 512)` features. You just need to load your images into an array, much like you do right now. It will probably take a lot of time and memory though. For that you can simply call `model.predict(x)` with smaller batches in a for loop. Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @umutto I see, it works, thank you! I created `.npy` file from the images and fed it to `model.predict`